# Change label text with value from different file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have these functions here that will record the time between starting point and pressing a button to stop the time, then finally print the length of time recorded:

```
-(void)informToPress
{
    textLabel.text = @"Test, press the button";
    //begin record and end record on button press

    startDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];
}

-(IBAction)stopTime{
    stopDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];
    textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time : %f", [stopTimer timeIntervalSinceDate:startTimer]]; 
}
```

But where I have:

```
textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time : %f", [stopTimer timeIntervalSinceDate:startTimer]];
```

I need this to be placed in a different View, and therefore a different .m file! How could I use this line of code in a completely different file? As the new file/view doesn't know what the values are or textLabel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a singleton called dateManager with the properties startTimer and stopTimer.

You will create only one instance of dateManager so it will be the same value for your properties anywhere in the code.

Or you can also create in one .h file (it's easier):

```
static NSDate *startTimer  = nil;
static NSDate *stopTimer  = nil;
```

And give them values when you need but don't forget to include the .h file where you need the variables.

And the right way to initiate a NSDate with the current date is to do like this :

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
```